# Postgres: Dumping and restoring a live database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm having some trouble backing up and restoring a database in pgAdmin.
With pgAdmin, the backup is pretty simple.

If I try to restore the data to my live database, I get all kinds of foreign key errors and duplicate data. So the only way for me now is to drop all constraints, drop all tables and run the restore.

Is there a simpler way to restore a live database? My systems are not directly connected, I'm using file transfer to copy over the backed up db dump.

Comment: Check out the docs on continuous archiving and point-in-time-recovery

Comment: You can specify `--clean` for `pg_restore` do drop all objects before importing. Or - if you are doing a SQL dump - you can specify `--clean` when running `pg_dump` to include the necessary `DROP` statements in the generated SQL script.

Comment: I ended up making a batch file for both sides, it ended up being simpler than trying to figure it out with the GUI.